# How to merge 2 win32com functions in python?

Tags: python, excel, vba

These two functions suppose will open the 2 vba excel files to run. 
How can I merge these two functions into one so that the `xlsm` file can run one by one accordindly?

```py
def  firstfile():
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=r'\\serverdrive\excel1.xlsm',ReadOnly=1)
    xl.Quit()

def  secondfile():
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=r'\\serverdrive\excel2.xlsm',ReadOnly=1)
    xl.Quit()
```

These are the attempts that I tried.

```py
def  firstfile():
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    x2=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=r'\\serverdrive\excel1.xlsm',ReadOnly=1)
    x2.Workbooks.Open(Filename=r'\\serverdrive\excel2.xlsm',ReadOnly=1)
    xl.Quit()
    x2.Quit()
```

```py
def  firstfile():
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=r'\\serverdrive\excel1.xlsm',ReadOnly=1)
    x1.Workbooks.Open(Filename=r'\\serverdrive\excel2.xlsm',ReadOnly=1)
    xl.Quit()
```

Comment: So what was wrong with your attmpts? This question is lacking a proper error description.

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ, I was trying to run the python script using Task Scheduler. It works fine when I run the scripts in seperate functions, but there is no response when I try to merge them into a single function. Just want to check if I use the win32com package in a correct way.. Thanks!

Comment: If the first two procedures in your example code work both, then change in your last example `x1.` (one) to `xl.` (lower case `L`) in the second file open line. That should make it work. • Run your python code manuall first before you try the task scheduler to make sure it works.